# Generating a variable name whose name has elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, variables

I'm trying to create variables with their name dependent on a vector

For example I want to generate a variable name called `P_00` but the 0's are actually elements of a vector

```
# Vector with two positions at 0: v[1] = 0, v[2] = 0
v = rep(0, 2)

# Create variable P_00 and assign 0.75
Pv[1]v[2] = .75
```

where `v[1]=0` and `v[2]=0` so if I were to call `P_00` it would display `.75`

Answer (score 2):

The `assign` function should work for this, for example:

```
v <- c(0, 0)
val <- 0.75
assign(sprintf('P_%d%d', v[1], v[2]), val)

> P_00
[1] 0.75
```

More info [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html).

Comment: Nice use of `sprintf`!